# Extracting text from the input field - using Webdriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

How would I extract the text from the input filed? I tried using XPath/CSSSelector but I'm getting an empty text and since its a input field.

Here is my html code:

```
<div>
     <input type="text" style="width:110px;" class="display">
</div>
```

Result: 1 to 50 of 195 rows

Here is the screen shot of the input field:

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to get the field's value.  For example: `element.get_attribute("value")`

Comment: this will fail if an input element has a defined attribute named 'value'. In which case, you need to do `driver.execute_script("var val = document.querySelector(selector).value; return val;")`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using C# so here is the working complete code:

```
public string TextAttributeValueByCssSelector(By by)
{
   var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
   return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by)).GetAttribute("value");
}
```