# Selenium - HTML input Text displays text but doesnt contain value

Tags: selenium

I'm trying a Selenium automation at site http://www.unitconverters.net/
Type any value for conversion at "From" input field. Now try and Inspect the value at "To" field.

Could someone please explain as how to get the value from "To" Field. When you inspect it doesn't contain any text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting text from the input field - using Webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803660/extracting-text-from-the-input-field-using-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

With `<input>` tags you can use `getAttribute("value")`

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.name("toVal")).getAttribute("value");
```

`getAttribute("innerHTML")` and `getAttribute("innerText")` could also work.